# Number of yarn applications getting launched as soon as hadoop services gets up. Cluster is 4 nodes ie. Hadoop HA cluster

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, high-availability

Hadoop-HA cluster - 4 nodes
As soon as I start hadoop services unnecessary yarn applications gets launched and no application logs gets generated. Not able to debug problem without logs. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjvkB.png

Comment: Click `History` link to find the error message

Comment: Number of applications getting submitted looks like there might be some script trying to run something in cycle. You can try backtracking what it is by sniffing traffic to YARN API ports using tcpdump on the node where active yarn ResourceManager is running.

Answer (score 0):

Never come across such issue. But it seems that there is some script or may be some oozie job triggering these apps. Try Yarn-Clean if this is of any help.

[Yarn-Clean](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/autoclean/)